# Adding a widget in Facebook wall

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook

How do I add a widget to Facebook wall? 
So when a user clicks on wall post, it gets opened there only, like YouTube video/audio.

It's certainly possible, as Slideshare app (http://apps.facebook.com/slideshare/) does it.

And, I see that it's a Flash component. I have an iframe (Javascript/html) widget.

Comment: I don't know about iframe/javascript/html widgets but to put Flash widgets in wall post, you have to require permission from Facebook and get on their whitelist (you don't need to be a big service like Slideshare or YouTube to get on the whitelist).

Comment: I found that, you can add Flash very easily... No need to whitelist now, but how to add iframe/javascript component, i think its not possible. thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know facebook documentation is not the best in the world, but [they have topic](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/) about adding flash into the wall.

You could have problems with the width size of you flash, 'cos the height is not really limited by width is limited to the width of the wall, and they like to change it really often, and in this way destroy all you old wall posts.

Comment: yup, It helped, and very easy to add flash on wall. But I want to do for javascript/iframe. Don't think its possible.

Comment: if you want to add iframe into the wall post, than yes, it's impossible, 'cos in that case people would add there a whole web pages with red blinking java script animation that crash users browsers.